# Python and Node.js gyp Error

Tags: python, node.js

I encountered a `gyp` error on my Windows 8 environment.
I followed these steps:

1:installed nodejs, downloaded `node-v0.12.7-x64.msi` from nodejs.org

2:created a new floder and made it a `virtualenv`

3:`venv/sourse/activate`

4:cloned an item from github

5:installed the python packages such as flask...

6:`npm install`

An error occured：

```
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe node_modules\pangyp\bin\node-gyp rebuild --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsa ss_ldflags= --libsass_library=                                                                                                

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install                                                                           
gyp ERR! configure error                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! stack Error: node-v0.12.7.tar.gz local checksum 88bc1dbe3f1da75a4b5eabea55ab1f40a99373b8ae7356d2374e8053ced04ec0 no  
42e53067127a5061415be7e12f39d                                                                                                 
gyp ERR! stack     at deref (E:\project1_2\shijuan\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\pangyp\lib\install.js:304:20)          
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (E:\project1_2\shijuan\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\pangyp\lib\install.js:3  
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)                                                                         
gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\project1_2\shijuan\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\pangyp\node_mod  
gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)                                                                 
gyp ERR! stack     at _stream_readable.js:908:16                                                                              
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)                                                                  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600                                                                                           
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\project1_2\\shijuan\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\pang  
ibsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="                                                                     
gyp ERR! cwd E:\project1_2\shijuan\node_modules\node-sass                                                                     
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! pangyp -v v2.3.0                                                                                                     
gyp ERR! not ok                                                                                                               
Build failed
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the package.json

```
 {
```

"repository": {

```
"type": "git",
"url": ""
```

},

"license": "MIT",

"description": "Project Shijuan",

"scripts": {

```
"start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config conf/webpack.config.js --progress --colors --port 5001 --content-base build/public",

"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config conf/webpack.config.js --progress --profile --colors"
```

},

"dependencies": {
    "amazeui": "^2.4.2",

```
"babel-core": "^5.4.7",

"babel-loader": "^5.1.3",

"coffee-loader": "^0.7.2",

"coffee-script": "^1.9.3",

"css-loader": "^0.15.6",

"echarts": "^2.2.7-webpack",

"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.1",

"file-loader": "^0.8.4",

"html-loader": "^0.3.0",

"jquery": "^2.1.4",

"manifest-revision-webpack-plugin": "^0.0.5",

"node-sass": "^3.2.0",

"postcss-loader": "^0.5.1",

"sass-loader": "^2.0.0",

"style-loader": "^0.12.3",

"superagent": "^1.3.0",

"url-loader": "^0.5.6",

"vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",

"vue": "^0.12.10",

"vue-loader": "^2.1.1",

"vue-validator": "^1.4.0",

"webpack": "^1.10.0",

"webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0",

"zrender": "ecomfe/zrender"
```

}
}